# How can I get code coverage for my windows driver

Tags: windows, driver

I am developing drivers for windows for SOCs, I need a way to get the code coverage in percentage for my driver, but it seems lots of tools are for apps, they don't work for windows kernel

Is there some info I don't know? How can I get the coverage for windows kernel?

Comment: Do you test Driver Coverage Toolkit ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/driver-coverage-toolkit

Comment: Thank you Mojtaba, but I think this is not the "code" coverage tool, it more than an tool for function coverage.

Answer (score 0):

[Bullseye](https://www.bullseye.com/) supports kernel mode code coverage.

Comment: Could you add a little more detail and maybe a small guide on how to use this? Link only answers do help, but it's always better to have some context for people with similar problems.